# Solving for percentage of restaurant customer type in R

Tags: r

I've tried this code to separate out restaurants to try and solve for percentage of restaurants in total customer_type:

`restaurantcust <- ColSolare[ColSolare$customer_type==restaurant, ]`

But I'm getting an this error:

> Error in [.data.frame(ColSolare, ColSolare$customer_type ==
> restaurant,  :    object 'restaurant' not found

Comment: use restaurantcust <- ColSolare[ColSolare$customer_type=="restaurant", ]`

Comment: This worked, thanks so much!